# How to split a string array into small chunk arrays in java?

Tags: java

Below is the example of the code snippet which needs the help

Example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

- if the chunk size is `1`, `[1,2,3,4,5]`
- if the chunk size is `2`, `[1,2]` and `[3,4]` and `[5]`
- if the chunk size is `3`, `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5]`
- if the chunk size is `4`, `[1,2,3,4]` and `[5]`

Java (from comment):

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  if (count == chunksize) {
    //do something and initialize
    counter = 0;
  }
  counter++; 
}
```

Comment: If the chunk size is 1, why isn't the result [1] and [2] and [3] and [4] and [5] ?

Comment: have you tried something? Can you share what you tried if you already did?

Comment: you can ignore the chunk 1, i just gave an example..we can check the size and the chunk is equal...when the case is equal we don't need chunks at all

Comment: Well, we can ignore it, or you can provide correct examples ...

Comment: int counter = 0; for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) { if(count == chunksize) { //do something and initialize counter = 0; } counter++;

Answer (score 36):

You can use `Arrays.copyOfRange(int[] original, int from, int to)`
The code could be something like this:

```
int chunk = 2; // chunk size to divide
for(int i=0;i<original.length;i+=chunk){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(original, i, Math.min(original.length,i+chunk))));
}
```

Comment: so for random chunk need one more loop??

Comment: What do you mean by random chunk?

Comment: random chunk means if i want for all chunk values..(1,2,3,4)

Comment: Yes, Just replace chunk=2 part by a for loop.

Comment: I liked in this way. Thanks

Answer (score 29):

Just stumbled upon this post after encountering the same question. Here is how I solved it (I used `Arrays.copyOfRange()`:

```
public static int[][] splitArray(int[] arrayToSplit, int chunkSize){
    if(chunkSize<=0){
        return null;  // just in case :)
    }
    // first we have to check if the array can be split in multiple 
    // arrays of equal 'chunk' size
    int rest = arrayToSplit.length % chunkSize;  // if rest>0 then our last array will have less elements than the others 
    // then we check in how many arrays we can split our input array
    int chunks = arrayToSplit.length / chunkSize + (rest > 0 ? 1 : 0); // we may have to add an additional array for the 'rest'
    // now we know how many arrays we need and create our result array
    int[][] arrays = new int[chunks][];
    // we create our resulting arrays by copying the corresponding 
    // part from the input array. If we have a rest (rest>0), then
    // the last array will have less elements than the others. This 
    // needs to be handled separately, so we iterate 1 times less.
    for(int i = 0; i < (rest > 0 ? chunks - 1 : chunks); i++){
        // this copies 'chunk' times 'chunkSize' elements into a new array
        arrays[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayToSplit, i * chunkSize, i * chunkSize + chunkSize);
    }
    if(rest > 0){ // only when we have a rest
        // we copy the remaining elements into the last chunk
        arrays[chunks - 1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayToSplit, (chunks - 1) * chunkSize, (chunks - 1) * chunkSize + rest);
    }
    return arrays; // that's it
}
```

#### And the results:

```
chunkSize = 1
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]

chunkSize = 2
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5]

chunkSize = 3
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]

chunkSize = 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5]

chunkSize = 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

chunkSize = 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Solid implementation. Actually gives a full and correct answer to the question at hand.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind importing Google Guava and converting to a List, there is a method for partitioning Lists:

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-

The following may achieve the desired result:

```
List<Integer> listToBeSplit = Arrays.asList(sourceArray);
int chunkSize = 3;
Lists.partition(listToBeSplit, chunkSize);
```

Comment: There is also an Apache Commons Collections ListUtils.partition() method.

Answer (score 5):

Using pure Java 8:

```
public class Chunk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = {1,2,3,4,78,999,-1,456};
        int chunkSize = 3;

        int[][] chunked = chunk(input, chunkSize);

        Arrays.stream(chunked)
                .map(Arrays::toString)
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static int[][] chunk(int[] input, int chunkSize) {
        return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + chunkSize)
                .limit((long) Math.ceil((double) input.length / chunkSize))
                .mapToObj(j -> Arrays.copyOfRange(input, j, j + chunkSize > input.length ? input.length : j + chunkSize))
                .toArray(int[][]::new);
    }
}

[1, 2, 3]
[4, 78, 999]
[-1, 456]
```

Comment: `j + chunkSize > input.length ? input.length : j + chunkSize` can be replaced with 
`Math.min(j + chunkSize, input.length)`

Answer (score 4):

```
        import java.util.Arrays;

        public class ArrayChunk {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};

                
                 int[][] chunks1 = ArrayChunk(array, 1);
                 print(chunks1);
                 int[][] chunks2 = ArrayChunk(array, 2);
                 print(chunks2);
                 int[][] chunks3 = ArrayChunk(array, 3);
                 print(chunks3);

                 
                 
            }

            public static int[][] ArrayChunk(int[] array, int chunkSize) {
                int numOfChunks = (int) Math.ceil((double) array.length / chunkSize);
                int[][] output = new int[numOfChunks][];

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
                    int start = i * chunkSize;
                    int length = Math.min(array.length - start, chunkSize);

                    int[] temp = new int[length];
                    System.arraycopy(array, start, temp, 0, length);
                    output[i] = temp;
                }

                //
                return output;
            }

            private static void print(int[][] output) {
                //
                System.out.println("======================");
                for (int[] x : output)
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
            }
            

        }



        ======================
        [1]
        [2]
        [3]
        [4]
        [5]
        ======================
        [1, 2]
        [3, 4]
        [5]
        ======================
        [1, 2, 3]
        [4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Iterate it and check to give the chunk size.

```
int chunkSize = userInput;
```

// iterate and check the condition

```
char[] resultArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputArray, start, end);
start = start + end;  // check whether the start will exceeds the length of the array
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[][] chunkArray(int[] array, int chunkSize) {
        // first we need to get number of chunks by dividing length by chunkSize.
        int numOfChunks = (int)Math.ceil((double)array.length / chunkSize);
// we declare 2d array to save in the chunks
        int[][] output = new int[numOfChunks][];

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
            int start = i * chunkSize;
            int length = Math.min(array.length - start, chunkSize);

            int[] temp = new int[length];
            System.arraycopy(array, start, temp, 0, length);
            output[i] = temp;
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   for(int i=0;i<list.size();){
    ArrayList<Integer>row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int k=0;
    while(k < chunksize){
        chunk.add(list.get(i));
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    System.out.println(chunk);
    nestedlist.add(chunk);
}
```

where list is a 1 dimension array and chunk is a nested array of size `chunksize`

Comment: Your solution wont work in some cases. What if `list.size()` is 1 and `chunksize` is 3

Answer (score 0):

In general you could use [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28boolean[],%20int,%20int%29) to copy

Comment: Please add essential information from the link in your answer. Link-only answers should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
public static List<String> split(String string, int chunk) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(([0-9]+,){" + (chunk - 1)
            + "}[0-9]+)|[0-9]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find())
        result.add("[" + matcher.group() + "]");

    return result;
}
```

Test code:

```
for (int chunkSize = 1; chunkSize < 6; ++chunkSize) {
    System.out.println("test for chunk size: " + chunkSize);
    for (String string : split("[1,2,3,4,5]", chunkSize))
        System.out.format("\t%s\n", string);
}
```

Output:

```
test for chunk size: 1
    [1]
    [2]
    [3]
    [4]
    [5]
test for chunk size: 2
    [1,2]
    [3,4]
    [5]
test for chunk size: 3
    [1,2,3]
    [4]
    [5]
test for chunk size: 4
    [1,2,3,4]
    [5]
test for chunk size: 5
    [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class ArrayChunk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] chunked = chunkArray("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".split(","), 2);
        System.out.println("Array with chunk size 2");
        Arrays.stream(chunked).forEach(strings -> System.out.println(String.join(",", strings)));

        chunked = chunkArray("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".split(","), 3);
        System.out.println("Array with chunk size 3");
        Arrays.stream(chunked).forEach(strings -> System.out.println(String.join(",", strings)));

        chunked = chunkArray("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".split(","), 4);
        System.out.println("Array with chunk size 4");
        Arrays.stream(chunked).forEach(strings -> System.out.println(String.join(",", strings)));

        chunked = chunkArray("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".split(","), 5);
        System.out.println("Array with chunk size 5");
        Arrays.stream(chunked).forEach(strings -> System.out.println(String.join(",", strings)));
    }

    private static String[][] chunkArray(String[] array, int chunkSize) {
        int chunkedSize = (int) Math.ceil((double) array.length / chunkSize); // chunked array size
        String[][] chunked = new String[chunkedSize][chunkSize];
        for (int index = 0; index < chunkedSize; index++) {
            String[] chunk = new String[chunkSize]; // small array
            System.arraycopy(array, index * chunkSize, chunk, 0, Math.min(chunkSize, array.length - index * chunkSize));
            chunked[index] = chunk;
        }
        return chunked;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```sh
Array with chunk size 2
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,null

Array with chunk size 3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9

Array with chunk size 4
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,null,null,null

Array with chunk size 5
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,null
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do so,

```
    int loopcount = employeeList.size() / constCount;
    int leftcount = employeeList.size() % constCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < loopcount - 1; i++) {
        //query.setParameterList("values"+i, employeeList.subList(tempCount, tempCount + constCount));

        System.out.println(employeeList.subList(tempCount, tempCount + constCount));
        tempCount = tempCount + 1000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplitArrayIntoChunks {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] in = {1,2,3,4,5};
    chunks(in, 2);
  }

  private static void chunks(int[] in, int chunkSize) {
    List<int[]> outList = new ArrayList<>();

    int i = 0;

    while (i < in.length) {
        int[] out = Arrays.copyOfRange(in, i, Math.min(i + chunkSize, in.length));
        outList.add(out);
        out = new int[chunkSize + 1];
        i += chunkSize;
    }

    for (int[] ol: outList) {
        System.out.print("[");
        Arrays.stream(ol).forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println("]");
    }
  }
}
```

// Result: [12]
[34]
[5]

Answer (score 0):

```
    let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let idx = 0;
    let count = 0;
    let tempList = [];
    let resultList = [];
    let splitSize = 2
    
    while (idx <= array.length)
    {
        tempList.push(array[idx++]);
        count++;
        if (count == splitSize)
        {
            resultList.push(tempList);
            tempList = [];
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (!tempList.length)
    {
        resultList.push(tempList);
    }
console.log(resultList);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a few lines of code

```
int i=0;
while (i<array.length) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, i, Math.min(array.length, i+chunkSize))));
    i+=chunkSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q.Split the array into chunks with a specified size?
Answer:
public class SplitArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] original = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        int splitSize = 3;
        
        /* expected Output 
        [0, 1, 2]
        [3, 4, 5]
        [6, 7, 8]
        [9]
        */
    
        List<int[]> list = splitArray(original, splitSize);
        list.forEach(splitArray -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitArray)));

}
public static List<int[]> splitArray(int[] array, int splitSize) {
    List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int len=array.length;
    int arr[] = null;
    int size = splitSize;
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        if(k==0)
        arr=new int[size];
        arr[k]=array[i];
        k++;
        if(k>size-1) {
            k=0;
            result.add(arr);
            len=len-size;
            if(len<splitSize) {
                size=len;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use the methode toCharArray :

```
    // Custom input string
    String str = "12345678";

    // Creating array and storing the array
    // returned by toCharArray() method
    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();

    // Lastly printing the array elements
    for (char c : ch) {

        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

see more : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-string-to-character-array-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise, I was curious about a solution that uses the more declarative style that's available from Java 8 with `Streams`.

First, here's a solution using streams, which works with a generic `List<T>` (not what the question asked for) of objects of type T to be 'chunked' :

```java
   public static <T> List<List<T>> chunkify(List<T> src, int chunkSize) {
      AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
      return src.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> index.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize)) // (1)
              .entrySet().stream()                         // (2)
              .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())          // (3)
              .map(Map.Entry::getValue)                    // (4)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());               // (5)
   }
```

For example, if we start with a `src` list of three integers:

```
List<Integer>
[1, 2, 3]
```

then (1) [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) with a `chunkSize` of `2` will provide a `Map` :

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>>
0 -> [1, 2], 1 -> [3]
```

(because `index.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize` will return [0, 0, 1], for the calls for the three integers in `src`)

(2) [`entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--).stream() provides a `Stream<Map.Entry>`:

```
Stream<Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>>
{key: 0, value: [1, 2]}, {key: 1, value: [3]}
```

(3) `sorted(Map.Entry.comparingKey())` ensures the correct ordering,  which is not guaranteed (I think!) by the output of the `groupingBy` method, nor by `entrySet` which returns a `Set`

(4) `map(Map.Entry::getValue)` extracts the chunks from the `Stream` of `Map.Entry` values:

```
Stream<List<Integer>>
[1, 2], [3]
```

(5) `collect` is used to convert this to a `List<List<Integer>>`

---

But the original question specified that

- the input was an array of `int`, and
- the result was some kind of collection if `int` arrays

So, here's a solution that takes an `int[]` and returns a `List<int[]>`.
It uses the same algorithm as above, but now adds the

- conversion between `int[]` and `Stream<Integer>` at the start, and
- conversion between `Stream<List<Integer>>` and `Stream<int[]>` at the end.

```java
   public static List<int[]> chunkify(int[] src, int chunkSize) {
      AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
      return Arrays.stream(src)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> index.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(list -> list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
```

This solution is made ugly (IMO) by the conversions at the start and the end.

As I said, this was an exercise (for me!), and one in which I was not interested in the performance of the algorithm.