# How to divide the Array in parts without loop

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

Can I get the array values from middle or any fixed position.
for example I have 1000 object in array and now I want to get 1 to 100 and 100 to 200 and so on till 900 to 1000 without loop.

Comment: do you want to store them elsewhere or just access them from array?

Comment: Use "chunks" :) see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857011/how-to-split-a-string-array-into-small-chunk-arrays-in-java

Comment: @KaranMer i just want to access

Answer (score 2):

You can use [copyOfRange()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int))

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(Object[] src, int from, int to)
```